# Multiple teams for one project in Visual Studio - bad practice?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

Previously I have been using Bitbucket with git; and I might have a dozen or so repositories for each project.

Python modules work especially well with this layout; as you can add each dependant module into `requirements.txt`; and it additionally allows you to reduce merge issues when working in a team; and helps with decoupling and increasing cohesion.

Starting to use Visual Studio online with Azure (still git though); and I was wondering if this approach to software engineering is still viable.

Would you recommend setting up a "Visual Studio Online Project" for each of my Python modules?

Answer (score 4):

With VSO there isn't a 1-1 relationship between projects and repositories; a project may contain more than 1 repo. I would suggest a single team project with multiple repositories would work better for you. If you want to logically contain work items to align with the repos, I'd use area paths.

Comment: Thanks; I created *k* area paths (_admin/_areas) and *k* git repositories (_admin/_versioncontrol). How do I associate new MSVC Solutions I associate with this Visual Studio Online Team with git repositories?

Comment: To add git repos to your team project, you can do it from the Code hub in the web UI and then clone them. About half way down http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2013-may-13-vso.aspx you will see screenshots showing the UI to do it.